# Add if statement to cmd.exe script

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I have a cmd.exe script:

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims==<ms" %i IN ('ping -n 1 -4 host1.internal ^|find "Reply from"') DO @echo %i
```

Basically, it returns ping value to host1.internal without anything else. I want to add if else statement so that if returned value is empty space, then return 0.

I tried to do it like this: `... DO IF %i (@echo %i) IF NOT %i (@echo 0)`, but it returns `( was unexpected at this time` and that's quite confusing.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but all 4 answers that currently are posted are not really helping - I need the exact response the script gets as of now and if ping wasn't successul, then return 0. As example, pinging google.com it should return "10" (as in 10ms) and pinging notexistinghost.com it should return "0".

Comment: In that case, I think your problem is that if there are no matches nothing is executed. You'll have to think your code in another way. I got confused by the solution you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If FIND fails, then echo out a line that will parse into your desired output.

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims==<ms" %i IN ('ping -n 1 -4 host1.internal ^|find "Reply from"^|^|echo XmXmXmXm0') DO @echo %i
```

*Explanation*

FIND returns with success (ERRORLEVEL 0) if string is found, failure (ERRORLEVEL 1) if string is not found.

The `&&` operator conditionally executes a command if the prior command succeeded, and `||` conditionally executes if the prior command failed. The `||` must be escaped as `^|^|` for the same reason that your pipe is escaped. The ECHO is simply printing a line that has a `0` in the 5th token.

Comment: Wow, thanks, just what I wanted and looks very cool. Accepting as best answer, but would you mind/have time to explain how that actually happens? (`^|^|` part and `XmXmXmXm0` part)

Comment: @the_lay - explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims==<ms" %%i IN ('ping -n 1 -4 host1.internal ^|find "Reply from"') DO set "replay=%%i"
if defined replay (echo(%replay%) else echo(0
```

.. same code for the command line:

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims==<ms" %i IN ('ping -n 1 -4 host1.internal ^|find "Reply from"') DO if "%i" equ "" (echo(0) else echo(%i
```

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to make it "one-liner"? I don't want to make it as .bat file, I want it to be runnable in cmd.exe just like that.

Comment: @the_lay - I made an edit, but can't test this. My `ping`  has other output.

Comment: Your last edit cannot work because there will not be an iteration if FIND fails. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16606860/1012053) for a one liner that works.

Comment: @dbenham - thank you, I thought it belonges to the language version and stopped testing too soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute multiple statements inside DO this way:

```
@FOR /L %%i in (1, 1, 5) DO @(
@echo %%i
@IF %%i==1 (@echo First)
@IF NOT %%i==1 (@echo Other)
)
```

Each command in its line grouped by '()'. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but another way of achieving your goal (assuming it's a test if a host exists/is reachable) would be to use conditional execution:
`ping -n 1 -4 host1.internal >nul && echo "Host replied" || echo "Host not replied"`

This uses status returned by command (ping in this instance) to execute appropriate command - `&&` means on success and `||` on failure. You could also use errorlevel tests, but I personally find conditionals more readable especially directly on command line.

Additional plus is it is not language dependent (ping returns localized strings for various languages in Win).

Comment: I need result in numbers back, not just "OK" or "Fail" result. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method to check success or failure of ping.

```
@echo off
ping -n 1 -4 host1.internal >nul && (echo ping succeeded) || (echo ping failed)
```

Comment: I need result in numbers back, not just "OK" or "Fail" result. Thanks anyway!